# jQuery Remove LI elements inside UL

Tags: jquery, html-lists, appendto

I am trying to fetch stores depending on the state the user Selects from a drop down.

```
<select name="addressInput" id="state" class="mx-stateSelect" onchange='getRetailers()'>
    <option value=""> Choose State</option>
    <option value="Alberta"> Alberta Canada</option>
    <option value="Alaska"> Alaska </option>
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
    ...
    <option value="Washington"> Washington </option>
</select>
```

**jQuery Function**

```
function getRetailers() {
    var state = $('#state').val();
    var searchUrl = 'getRetailers.php?state=' + state;

    $.getJSON(searchUrl, function(data) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<li id="' + val.id + '"><a href="#" data-lat="' + val.lat + '" data-lng="' + val.lng + '">' + val.name + '<br/>' + val.address + ', ' + val.city + ', ' + val.zipcode + ' ' + val.stab + '</a></li>');
        });


        $('<ul/>', {
            'class' : 'mx-retailers',
            html : items.join('')
        }).appendTo('.mx-retailerResult');
    });
}
```

This is adding another set of UL LI to the code. Where as i want to replace the old LI with the new LI i fetch from the database.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="mx-retailerResult">
    <ul class="mx-retailers">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to remove all the LI Element inside the UL and replace it with Fresh content from the database

Comment: What is your question about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<ul/>', {
    'class' : 'mx-retailers',
    html : items.join('')
}).appendTo('.mx-retailerResult');
```

the above code creates a new ul element try

```
$('ul.mx-retailers').html(items.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

This block of code you have is creating a new UL element with a class of `mx-retailers`:

```
$('<ul/>', {
            'class' : 'mx-retailers',
            html : items.join('')
        }).appendTo('.mx-retailerResult');
```

If you dont want to do this then replace it with the following:

```
items.join('').appendTo('.mx-retailerResult');
```

This will add all of your li elements into the ul with the class of `mx-retailerResult`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mx-retailerResult').html($('<ul/>', {
    'class' : 'mx-retailers',
    html : items.join('')
}));
```